# How to save PDF file into MYSQL database? (PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, database, pdf

I'm trying to save all the information inserted by user into the database, all the info are able to save except the pdf file.

```
    public function insertUM() {
        if($_POST['um-area']) {
            $this->usermanual = strip_tags($this->usermanual);              
            $queryInsert = "INSERT INTO ".$this->usermanualFiles." (area, subject, description, filename) VALUES('".$_POST['um-area']."', '".$_POST['um-subject']."', '".$_POST['um-description']."', '".$_FILES['pdf']['name']."')";

            mysqli_query($this->dbConnect, $queryInsert);

            $uploadDirectory = 'pdf/';

            $targetFile = $uploadDirectory . basename($_FILES['pdf']['name']);

            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['pdf']['tmp_name'], $targetFile)) {
                echo "The file " . basename($_FILES['pdf']['name']) . " has been uploaded.";
            } else {
                echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
            }
            if ($_FILES['pdf']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
                echo "File upload failed with error code: " . $_FILES['pdf']['error'];
                exit;
            }
        }
    }
```

following is the example outcome:
[image]

Comment: Your code is wide open to sql injection. To save the file, using `move_uploaded_file` your current path is simply `pdf/` - I would be tempted to provide the full path at that point, like `__DIR__ . '/pdf'`

Answer (score 2):

You should save the pdf file on disk and only save the file path in the database

Comment: Could you please give an example of how to do it? I tried something like this but it doesn't work

 $uploadDirectory = 'pdf/';

            $targetFile = $uploadDirectory . basename($_FILES['pdf']['name']);

            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['pdf']['tmp_name'], $targetFile)) {
                echo "The file " . basename($_FILES['pdf']['name']) . " has been uploaded.";
            } else {
                echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
            }

Comment: <form action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <label for="file">文件名：</label>
 <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="提交">
</form>

Comment: <?php
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
{
 echo "错误：" . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
}
else
{
 echo "上传文件名: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
 echo "文件类型: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
 echo "文件大小: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
 echo "文件临时存储的位置: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
}

Comment: Sorry, there is Chinese in the comment. My English is not very good.

Comment: It's ok, I'll try, 谢谢

Answer (score 0):

Actually, MySQL database cannot support saving files directly, so you need 2 steps:

provide an API to upload the PDF file to your disk and create the path of your uploaded
then save the path you uploaded to the database